# Azure Ad B2B authentication retrieve data from external user CRM

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, azure-ad-b2b

We want to build a web app through which Dynamics crm customer's can login. Once they login we would like to show them their CRM's instance contact list. We have implemented Azure B2B Authentication and hosted app but I don't know how to retrieve data from logged in customer's crm .

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-3-Multi-Tenant/README.md#about-this-sample

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [CRM connection string examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/xrm-tooling/use-connection-strings-xrm-tooling-connect#connection-string-examples). You can prompt logged in user for authentication. It creates a new connection to Common Data Service using the current logged in user via OAuth.

I wanted to connect to CRM to work with solutions for a project, so I used to CRM SDK for that by referring to [PowerApps samples](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerApps-Samples) repo. And my project authenticates user using Azure B2B, and I wanted the same user to connect to CRM. So I used [On-Behalf-Of flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow).
I first got access token after authenticating user for the AD app. Then I used this token to get another token using UserAssertion for the target org (Ex: https://org12345.crm.dynamics.com/). You'll need to add Dynamics CRM permission like this [Registering AD App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/walkthrough-register-app-azure-active-directory). Now once I have the token for my target org, I use it like this to connect to CRM:

```
 Uri serviceUrlDestination = new Uri(orgUrl + @"/xrmservices/2011/organization.svc/web?SdkClientVersion=8.2");

 OrganizationWebProxyClient sdkServiceDestination = new OrganizationWebProxyClient(serviceUrlDestination, false);

 sdkServiceDestination.HeaderToken = AccessToken;
            CrmServiceClient serviceClient = new CrmServiceClient(sdkServiceDestination);
```

I don't know how to retrieve contact list of the logged in user as I used this for mainly for solutions, but once you are connected to CRM from the logged in user's context, I think you should be able to do other operations as well.